# using placeholder in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display the placeholder value in textbox. When user try to type in textbox it will erase automatically from the textbox. Can anyone resolve it?

Comment: show your effort what you have tried ???

Comment: http://vidmar.net/weblog/archive/2008/11/05/watermarked-textbox-in-windows-forms-on-.net.aspx  took less than 30 seconds to search for

Answer (score 2):

Use the events when the text box gets focus and loses focus. When the textbox gets focus you do something like `MytextBox.Text = string.Emtpy` when it loses focus you check to see whether it has content or not and if not you set it to your default value something like: 
`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MytextBox.Text) ? "Default" : MytextBox.Text`